# Vue named slots do not work when wrapped

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a responsive-menu component which I want to use named slots inside of this up my template markup:

```
<template>
    <div class="responsive-menu">
        <div class="menu-header">
            <slot name="header"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Whenever I try my named slot like this it work perfectly fine:

```
<responsive-menu>
    <h3 slot="header">Responsive menu header</h3>
</responsive-menu>
```

However as soon as I wrap it with a class nothing shows up anymore.

```
<responsive-menu>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 slot="header">Responsive menu header</h3>
    </div>
</responsive-menu>
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't I just be able to wrap the named component? Which does it appear that my named slots need to be direct children of my Vue component?

Comment: Umm.. I reproduced your [case](http://jsfiddle.net/1t2puwtw/1/) and it works?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal You are using a header slot, yet your html does not have any reference to this slot. Meaning it will simply fall back to it's default slot content.

Comment: By the way I am using webpack with `.vue` components I will try if I can get a webpackbin file up and running.

Comment: The only thing I can think is OP is actually doing `<responsive-menu><another-component><slot>...</slot></another-component></responsive-menu>`. If that's not the case this works just fine.

Comment: I hadn't registered the component, now I see it blanked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work because your "wrapped slot" isn't direct child of responsive-menu tag.

try something like that:

```
<responsive-menu>
    <div class="container" slot="header">
        <h3>Responsive menu header</h3>
    </div>
</responsive-menu>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzLnd6c/1/)

Comment: The slot doesn't need to be a direct child.

Comment: I have tried it out and it does not need to be a direct child: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhXJnhf2meOIC9h5XS0 There is a problem with this example though because all the markup in my template surrounding the named slot is completely gone. And in my current codebase I still can't get it working properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that slot need to be a direct child. Check my fiddle

Comment: @Stephan-v in your example vue doesn't use named slot, but fallback to default slot. class menu-header is not present in rendered html

Comment: I'm looking at this a little closer and I think I'm wrong. It works if it's not a direct child, but not --correctly-- *as you'd expect*. http://jsfiddle.net/1t2puwtw/4/

Comment: If slot isn't direct child, slot attribute is ignored and ENTIRE content of component tag is used as content for default slot in component template markup.

Comment: @Stephan-v This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t2puwtw/6/) should prove the answer.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal So how would you make that particular fiddle working properly? Neverind I tried to remove the container and everything works than. I am really wondering if this is a bug or if this is meant to happen though.

Comment: @Stephan-v From what I see, It looks like it was meant to be this way, or else it wouldn't have fallen down to the default slot.

Answer (score 2):

It works with Vue >= 2.6. Just upgrade vue and vue-template-compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like `v-slot` because `slot` syntax is deprecated as mentioned [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots):

```
<responsive-menu>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 v-slot:header>Responsive menu header</h3>
    </div>
</responsive-menu>
```

or Alternatively, a shorthand:

```
<responsive-menu>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 #header>Responsive menu header</h3>
    </div>
</responsive-menu>
```